# How to move from one page to the next using ExpandableListView

Tags: android, navigation, expandablelistview, onclicklistener, expandablelistadapter

Does anyone know how to move to another page from the ExpandableListView.  I'm new to android so this is a little tricky.  So far, I have my ELV with headings and children.  However, what I want is when someone clicks on one of the children, it sends them to another page.  I'm lost so any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code I've done so far:

```
          public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;


      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
       }

        /     *
      * Preparing the list data
      */
    private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Lesson 1");
    listDataHeader.add("Lesson 2");
    listDataHeader.add("Lesson 3");
    listDataHeader.add("Lesson 4");
    listDataHeader.add("Lesson 5");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> Lesson1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Lesson1.add("The Alphabet");
    Lesson1.add("Common Expressions");
    Lesson1.add("Vocabulary: Things in a Room");
    Lesson1.add("Grammar: Demonstrative Pronouns");
    Lesson1.add("Questions and Answers");


    List<String> Lesson2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Lesson2.add("Numbers 1-10");
    Lesson2.add("Common Expressions");
    Lesson2.add("Vocabulary: Classroom Tools");
    Lesson2.add("Grammar: Plurals");
    Lesson2.add("Grammar: Using Plurals");
    Lesson2.add("Questions and Answers");

    List<String> Lesson3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Lesson3.add("Numbers 11-20");
    Lesson3.add("Common Expressions");
    Lesson3.add("Vocabulary: School");
    Lesson3.add("Grammar: Possessives");
    Lesson3.add("Questions and Answers");

    List<String> Lesson4 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Lesson4.add("The Tens (20-100)");
    Lesson4.add("Common Expressions");
    Lesson4.add("Vocabulary: Food");
    Lesson4.add("Grammar: Subject Pronouns, Using 'Want'");
    Lesson4.add("Questions and Answers");

    List<String> Lesson5 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Lesson5.add("Numbers 21-30");
    Lesson5.add("Common Expressions");
    Lesson5.add("Vocabulary: Common Verbs I");
    Lesson5.add("Grammar: Using 'Want' + Infinitive");
    Lesson5.add("Questions and Answers");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), Lesson1); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), Lesson2);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), Lesson3);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), Lesson4);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), Lesson5);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
```

I've created an adapter class as follows:

```
       public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you will find this tutorial helpful http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: also this one http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129